# Количество серверов

Tags: discord

Как сделать так, чтобы при включении бота, он показывал в консоли количество серверов(где он находиться)

Не рабочий код:

```
async def on_server_join(server):
    print(f"{server.name}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `on_server_join()` вызывается тогда, когда на сервер, где есть бот, заходит новый пользователь.

Вам же нужно, чтобы бот выводил информацию **при включении**, что сразу указывает на необходимость использования функции `on_ready()`, которая автоматически вызывается как только бот запущен и готов к работе.

В этой функции через цикл `for` будем выводить все сервера бота, которые он содержит в атрибуте `guilds`

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for server in bot.guilds:
        print(server.name)
```